# Pyramid: config.set_request_property callback never gets called

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying to set a callback with `config.set_request_property`, but the callback never gets called. No error messages, it just silently fails. Why is it not working? How can I track down where the problem is?

Here is the code I'm using in my `__init__`:

```
def callbackTest(request):
    print 'Callback worked!'
    return True

def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    # pyramid_beaker add-on  
    session_factory = session_factory_from_settings(settings)
    set_cache_regions_from_settings(settings)

    config = Configurator(root_factory=MongoRootFactory(settings), session_factory=session_factory, settings=settings)

    config.add_static_view('gfx', 'gfx', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_static_view('fonts', 'fonts', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_static_view('css', 'css/compiled', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_static_view('js', 'js/compiled', cache_max_age=3600)



    print 'callbackTest callback should be set...'
    config.set_request_property(callbackTest, 'user', reify=True)

    #********************************************************
    # Authentication
    #********************************************************
    authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(secret='asecret',
                                           callback=groupfinder)
    authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
    config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
    config.set_authorization_policy(authz_policy)


    #********************************************************
    # View setup
    #********************************************************

    config.add_route('IndexTest', '/')
    config.add_route('Home', '/h')



    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Can anyone see my error here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only error I see is that you don't show us where you are using the property? Properties are only invoked when you invoke them. Do you have code that is invoking `request.user` in a view, and you are getting an error because that property does not exist? If you are expecting the function to be automatically called every request, that's exactly what `set_request_property` is attempting to avoid.

Comment: This was the problem. I wasn't calling the property, and hence it the function wasn't being called. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

From the [pyramid.config](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.set_request_property) API documentation:

> callable can either be a callable that accepts the **request** as its single positional parameter[...]

Now I don't know if this may be causing your issue, but it needs accept a request for work (though I would expect an Exception being thrown, not a silent failure).

Comment: It was a good guess and a good correction, but I've tried including a request argument and the results are not different. I've updated my example with your correction.